# Dagger-2 - Can't access my xml resources

Tags: android, dagger-2

Sorry for the long question / code and my english skills :)
I want to use Dagger-2 in my new android app. I have no experience with Dagger-2 or other dependency libraries. I think i misunderstand something...

Here are the relevant application. If the activity "OverviewActivity" starts it injects the "OverviewPresenter" and so on.. (OverviewActivity->OverviewPresenter->CategoriesPovider->DBOpenHelper->DBDefaults).

At the first start the class DBDefaults should prefill the database with some default values. At the time it should access the resources files i get a NPE. Can anybody tell me why this happens? I tried to use the "Log" tool to check if any needed variable is null but everything looks fine. Gets the DBDefaults class the wrong context?

Finally the method throws a NPE

```
context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.category_colors);
```

But here is my code.
AppComponent.java

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = AppModule.class)
public interface AppComponent {
    Context getContext();
    Application getApplication();
    DBOpenHelper getDBOpenHelper();
}
```

AppModule.java

```
@Module
public class AppModule {
    private final Manager app;

    public AppModule(Manager app) {
        this.app = app;
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    public Application provideApplication() {
        return app;
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    public Context provideContext() {
        return app.getApplicationContext();
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    public DBOpenHelper provideDBOpenHelper() {
        return new DBOpenHelper(app);
    }
}
```

OverviewComponent.java

```
@ActivityScope
@Component(dependencies = AppComponent.class)
public interface OverviewComponent {
    void inject(OverviewActivity activity);
    OverviewPresenter getOverviewPresenter();
}
```

OverviewPresenter.java

```
public class OverviewPresenter extends MvpBasePresenter<OverviewView> {

    @Inject
    public OverviewPresenter(CategoriesProvider provider) {
        Log.d("OverviewPresenter", "presenter..");
    }
}
```

CategoriesProvider.java

```
public class CategoriesProvider extends BaseProvider {

    @Inject
    public CategoriesProvider(DBOpenHelper dbOpenHelper) {
        super(dbOpenHelper);
        // Just testing...
        dbOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    }
}
```

DBOpenHelper.java

```
public class DBOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String db = "manager";
    private static final int version = 1;
    private Context context;

    @Inject
    public DBOpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, db, null, version);
        this.context = context;
        Log.d("DBOpenHelper", "database...");
        if (context == null) {
            Log.d("DBOpenHelper", "wtf...");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // db structure
        db.execSQL(CategoriesTable.getCreateTableQuery());
        db.execSQL(UsersTable.getCreateTableQuery());

        // default values
        DBDefaults defaults = new DBDefaults(db, context);
        defaults.insertSystemUser();
        defaults.insertCategories();
    }
}
```

DBDefaults.java

```
public class DBDefaults {
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private Context context;

    public DBDefaults(SQLiteDatabase db, Context context) {
        this.db = db;
        this.context = context;
        if (context == null) {
            Log.d("DBDefaults", "wtf... in Defaults");
        }
    }

    public void insertCategories() {
        String[] test = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.category_colors);
        for (String item : test) {
            Log.d("Categories", item);
        }
        // NPE ?!?!?!
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
My Manger class. Here I'm storing my app component and init my AppModule

```
public class Manager extends Application {
    private AppComponent appComponent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder().appModule(new AppModule(this)).build();
    }

    public AppComponent getAppComponent() {
        return appComponent;
    }
}
```

My Activity

```
public class OverviewActivity extends MvpActivity<OverviewView, OverviewPresenter> {

    public OverviewComponent overviewComponent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation);
    }

    @Override
    public void inject() {
        Log.d("Activity", "inject");
        overviewComponent = DaggerOverviewComponent.builder()
                .appComponent(((MoneyManager)getApplication()).getAppComponent())
                .build();
        overviewComponent.inject(this);
    }

    @Override
    public OverviewPresenter getPresenter() {
        Log.d("Activity", "getPresenter");
        return overviewComponent.getOverviewPresenter();
    }
}
```

Comment: Post `Manager` class and the instantiation of `AppModule` and where you store your `AppComponent`

Comment: @EpicPandaForce - i edited my post. Thx

Comment: Out of curiousity, so you mean that `Log.d("DBDefaults", "wtf... in Defaults");` is NOT logged, and you get an NPE on the line `String[] test = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.category_colors)`? Do you have an `R.array`category_colors` for all configurations, and not just a specific one?

Comment: Yes.. this is NOT logged. Anyway - with the `getIntArray`the app is running. I don't know why. But thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

If `CategoriesProvider` is a `ContentProvider`, you might get `null` when calling `Application.getApplicationContext()`.  So the context that you're injecting could be null. You can verify this in `AppModule`. Try logging the result before returning it. Note that `Application.getApplicationContext()` normally returns the same instance, so you could just `return app;` instead of what you currently have.